# Use salt-cloud AWS EC2 public IP in another minion's states

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, salt-stack

I have salt-cloud working with a map file to successfully provision a new EC2 instance:

```
$ sudo salt-cloud -m cloud/map.yaml
...
[INFO    ] Salt installed on us-west-1
[INFO    ] Created Cloud VM 'us-west-1'
[INFO    ] Complete
us-west-1:
...
$ salt -l debug 'us-west-1' test.ping
us-west-1:
    True
```

Now I need to use that instance's public IP in another minion's states for various bits of configuration.  What's the "Right Way" to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [this](https://github.com/saltstack/salt-contrib/blob/master/grains/external_ip.py) salt-contrib module. Very useful and works to get the public IP address not only for ec2. It creates a grain called external_ip that use external services to detect the current IP address. It's very simple.